# Flutter does not generate a lib/main.dart

Tags: visual-studio, flutter, dart

After opening a simulator, when I run:

flutter create first_app

on my Dev folder directory in my User account, and then I run:

cd first_app

flutter run

I am given an error message saying that there is no lib/main.dart directory, which is true; flutter didn't create a main file/method for me.

This consequently makes it impossible to run the app. I am only starting out with Flutter, so I have yet to learn how to create a main method etc...
My visualstudio code has already installed the Flutter Plugins.

Comment: do you have flutter plugin for vsccode?

Comment: @LoVe yes. VScode works; it's just that I can't run the app, since there is no main method.

Comment: then you create one

Comment: `flutter create` should have created a `lib/main.dart` file for you.  Can you run it again and verify that it didn't?  What version of Flutter are you using?