# Why no /lib dir and no main.dart file?

Tags: flutter, dart, directory, lib

When I ran "flutter create project_name" it did not  create a lib/main.dart file, hence it's unable to flutterrun it further. I've searched throughout stackflow such as the one here [Flutter does not generate a lib/main.dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61372630/flutter-does-not-generate-a-lib-main-dart), but no real solution to the missing lib directory and the missing main.dart file. Any one has any clue? Thanks!

Comment: `flutter create project_name` should create a `project_name/lib/main.dart` file.  Can you provide precise reproduction details?  What version of Flutter are you using?  What is your OS?  Exactly what commands did you run?  You say no `lib/main.dart` file was created, but did anything else happen?  Were any other directories or files created?

Comment: If the iOS and Android folders have been created, create a lib directory with an empty main.dart file inside

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I issued the flutter create btc_wallet command, and the directory and file structure was as follows: 

.dart_tool>>>
.idea>>>
android>>>
ios>>>
.gitignore
.packages
pubspec.lock
pubspec.yaml

Here >>> denotes a directory. 
You see there is no lib directory and hence no main.dart file.

My version of Flutter: flutter_1.20.4-stable
OS: Win 10
My commands:  
flutter create btc_wallet

Comment: By the way, when I created the Flutter project within Android Studio, the situation is the same.
You said: "If the iOS and Android folders have been created, ...", is that the correct way to get around the problem? 
Hee below my flutter doctor output:
[√] Flutter (Channel dev, 1.23.0-4.0.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1016], locale zh-CN)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available
! Doctor found issues in 1 category.